# How to execute Observable sequentially that is dependent to each other

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

I need advice on how I achieve the stated title.
My scenario is this. I have three methods in my service `isUserEnable()`, `isLicenseStatusEnable()` and `resetPassword()` and should be executed sequentially. First, I need to ensure that user is enabled. If user is enabled, I need to ensure that license status is enabled also. Then finally, I can now execute the reset method in my service. If any of the first 2 method return `false`, then it should abort the reset password and should not continue to execute the succeeding methods.

**Service**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PasswordResetService {
    isUserEnable(user: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return true;
    }

    isLicenseStatusEnable(user: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return true
    }

    resetPassword() {
        // reset password code
    }
}
```

I have the below code and put `delay(5000)` to simulate the execution. But, it was not executed one by one. I'm not sure how do I implement it to execute one by one.

```
  /**
   * Check user status
   */
  userPasswordReset() {
    let userEnabled ;

    this.passwordResetService.isUserEnable('example_user')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => TASKS_DATA[0].status = TaskStatus.Started),
        delay(5000),
        map(x => {
          TASKS_DATA[0].taskdescription = "User is enable";
          TASKS_DATA[0].status = TaskStatus.Success;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        userEnabled = result;
      });

    this.passwordResetService.isLicenseStatusEnable('example_user')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => TASKS_DATA[1].status = TaskStatus.Started),
        delay(5000),
        map(x => {
          TASKS_DATA[1].taskdescription = "License is enable";
          TASKS_DATA[1].status = TaskStatus.Success;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        return result;
      });
  }
```

Any suggestions will be very appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `async/await` but you need to convert the observable to promise by `toPromise`

```js
  async userPasswordReset() {

    const userEnabled = await this.passwordResetService.isUserEnable('example_user')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => TASKS_DATA[0].status = TaskStatus.Started),
        delay(5000),
        map(x => {
          TASKS_DATA[0].taskdescription = "User is enable";
          TASKS_DATA[0].status = TaskStatus.Success;
        })
      ).toPromise(); //  convert to Promise


    const result = this.isUserEnable.isLicenseStatusEnable('example_user')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => TASKS_DATA[1].status = TaskStatus.Started),
        delay(5000),
        map(x => {
          TASKS_DATA[1].taskdescription = "License is enable";
          TASKS_DATA[1].status = TaskStatus.Success;
        })
      ).toPromise(); //  convert to Promise

  }
```

> The [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function declaration defines an asynchronous function — a function that is an AsyncFunction object. Asynchronous functions operate in a separate order than the rest of the code via the event loop, returning an implicit Promise as its result. But the syntax and structure of code using async functions looks like standard synchronous functions.
>
> The [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.

read more about  [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

another way id to move the second opbservable to the body of the first observable subscribtion body

```js
this.passwordResetService.isUserEnable('example_user')
  .pipe(
    tap(_ => TASKS_DATA[0].status = TaskStatus.Started),
    delay(5000),
    map(x => {
      TASKS_DATA[0].taskdescription = "User is enable";
      TASKS_DATA[0].status = TaskStatus.Success;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    userEnabled = result;

      this.passwordResetService.isLicenseStatusEnable('example_user')
        .pipe(
          tap(_ => TASKS_DATA[1].status = TaskStatus.Started),
          delay(5000),
          map(x => {
            TASKS_DATA[1].taskdescription = "License is enable";
            TASKS_DATA[1].status = TaskStatus.Success;
          })
        )
        .subscribe(result => {
          return result;
        });

  });
```

> the `async/await` is more readable and if you have more than two observable you will have a structure like callback hell so I am  recomand the `async/await`

Comment: hey @malbarmavi, this works as I want to behave. Would you mind to explain a little bit on the code you have provided? I'm not really getting the changes you have made in my initial code.

Comment: @klaydze I have add more example and clarification but you need to check the links I have provides have more extra information 

Comment: check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn3tm0quoqE&t=4s explain async/await very good

Comment: be aware that toPromise() is deprecated on rxjs7

Answer (score 0):

we can make use of `switchMap` operator from rxjs. You can find more information from below link:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

The switchMap is used for sequential flow and the advantage we have is it has only single subscription.

Below is the sample code for switchMap: (sequential API calls):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-operators-examples?file=src%2Fapp%2Fswitch-map%2Fswitch-map.component.ts

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

For calls that depend on previous result you should use concatMap operator operator from rxjs

```
firstApiCall().pipe(
    concatMap(result1 => secondAPICall())
      concatMap( result2 => thirdAPICall())
       concatMap(result3 => fourthAPICall())

).subscribe(
    success => { /* display success msg */ },
    errorData => { /* display error msg */ }
);
```

Comment: how do you cancel the succeeding concatMap if the `result1` not met your condition?